# Round a number to 2 or more decimal places

Tags: javascript, typescript, math, rounding

I'm working in TypeScript. Is there an accepted way of rounding a number to n decimal places, or more, if the precision exists in the number?

The number must be represented as a string to avoid precision errors (e.g. `2.3 - 2 = 0.2999999999999998`)

For example:

```
precision = [2, 6];

tx(0.000000, precision) => 0.00
tx(0.123123, precision) => 0.123123

tx(2.00, precision) => 2.00
tx(2, precision) => 2.00

tx(2.01, precision) => 2.01
tx(2.001, precision) => 2.001
tx(2.000000001, precision) => 2.00
tx(2.000001, precision) => 2.000001
```

I can use this to deal with funky epsilon errors while still allowing users to enter more precise numbers than a fixed DP.

Comment: In typescript and JS `0.00` is the same as `0`, just like `2.00` is the same as `2`.

Comment: The only way you can get `0.00` and not `0` is by using a string.

Comment: Yes, using a string is completely fine  I'll clarify in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) with [`minimumFractionDigits`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat#minimumfractiondigits) and [`maximumFractionDigits`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat#maximumfractiondigits) parameters

```js
function tx(value, [minimumFractionDigits, maximumFractionDigits]) {
  const result = value.toLocaleString('en-US', {
    minimumFractionDigits,
    maximumFractionDigits
  });
  
  console.log( {value, result} );
  return result;

}


const precision = [2, 6];

tx(0.000000, precision)
tx(0.123123, precision)

tx(2.00, precision)
tx(2, precision)

tx(2.01, precision)
tx(2.001, precision)
tx(2.000000001, precision)
tx(2.000001, precision)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice solution because it is language invariant and uses the language API so I have less code to maintain and test 

Answer (score 1):

You can try it like this, which is intentionally verbose:

```
type PrecisionRange = [min: number, max: number]

function tx(num: number, [min, max]: PrecisionRange): number {
  const withoutTrailingZeroes = `${num}`.replace(/0+$/, '') || '0.0'
  const digitsAfterDecimalSeparator = withoutTrailingZeroes.includes('.')
    ? withoutTrailingZeroes.split('.')[1].length
    : 0
  const toFixedDigits = Math.min(max, Math.max(min, digitsAfterDecimalSeparator))
  return Number(num.toFixed(toFixedDigits))
}

const precision: PrecisionRange = [2, 6]

console.log(tx(0.000000, precision))    // 0
console.log(tx(0.123123, precision))    // 0.123123

console.log(tx(2.00, precision))        // 2
console.log(tx(2, precision))           // 2

console.log(tx(2.01, precision))        // 2.01
console.log(tx(2.001, precision))       // 2.001
console.log(tx(2.000000001, precision)) // 2
console.log(tx(2.000001, precision))    // 2.000001
```

However, `0.00` as a number will always be displayed as `0`, as trailing zeroes after the decimal separator are not displayed. If you need them for display purposes, simply adapt the method shown above to this:

```
function tx(num: number, [min, max]: PrecisionRange): string {
    const withoutTrailingZeroes = `${num}`.replace(/0+$/, '') || '0.0'
    const digitsAfterDecimalSeparator = withoutTrailingZeroes.includes('.') 
      ? withoutTrailingZeroes.split('.')[1].length
      : 0
    const toFixedDigits = Math.min(max, Math.max(min, digitsAfterDecimalSeparator))
    return num.toFixed(toFixedDigits)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is clever.  It would need to be made language invariant (some places use a comma instead of a point).